# Hibernate- Sql query cast object

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I have Spring MVC Application alongside hibernate. I can cast hql queries to object but the same doesn't apply to SQL. I have the following query to cast to `Jpassatempos` Object:

```
List<Jpassatempos> list = (List<Jpassatempos>) 
session.createSQLQuery("select jpassatempos.* from jpassatempos 
left join jcodigos on jpassatempos.Id = jcodigos.PassatemposId 
where jpassatempos.Id in 
     (select jpassatempos_concorrentes.PassatemposId from jpassatempos_concorrentes  
       left join jpassatempos on jpassatempos_concorrentes.PassatemposId = jpassatempos.Id 
       where  jpassatempos_concorrentes.ConcorrentesId = ? and jpassatempos.DataFim > current_date group by jpassatempos_concorrentes.PassatemposId) 
or jpassatempos.Id in 
     (select  jmeuspassatempos.PassatemposId from jmeuspassatempos 
       where ConcorrentesId = ? group by jmeuspassatempos.PassatemposId) 
group by jpassatempos.Id order by sum(jcodigos.NumBolhasRestantes)").setParameter(0, id).setParameter(1, id).list();
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use setResultTransformer( Transformers.aliasToBean(Jpassatempos.class))

Comment: Should i use it like this:  

Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Jpassatempos.class);
   criteria.setResultTransformer(
                 Transformers.aliasToBean(Jpassatempos.class));

It didn't do anything...

Comment: No, createSqlQuery returns a  SQLQuery , so it has the method setResultTransformer.  createSqlQuery('sql').setParameter().setResultTranformer().list()

Comment: Thanks but i get another error:
Could not find setter for TipoPassatemposId on class com.setelog.spring.model.Jpassatempos
I supose it can't cast correctly because of related entities

Comment: try to use addEntity(Jpassatempos.class).    ex:......  createSqlQuery('sql').setParameter().addEntity(passatempos.class)